# Jquery Проверка наличия ключа объекта

Tags: jquery

подскажите как проверить наличие ключа в объекте именно на Jquery

```
var mas = ('search' in page)?{'search': page.search, 'pages': page.pages}:{'pages': page.pages};
```

Такой код выдает ошибку: TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got number

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, просто забыл вставить JSON строку в атрибут